# initrc_t bash: /etc/init.d/network: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: selinux

on my CentOS 7.6 with SELinux enforcing I faced with the issue:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=sysadm_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

#ls -lZ /etc/init.d/network
-rwxr-x---. root root system_u:object_r:initrc_exec_t:s0 /etc/init.d/network

#  /etc/init.d/network
bash: /etc/init.d/network: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied

# sh /etc/init.d/network
Usage: /etc/init.d/network {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}


# runcon -r sysadm_r /etc/init.d/network
Usage: /etc/init.d/network {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}
```

So, it looks like some restriction doesn't allow to execute files with initrc_exec_t type.
Any Ideas of how to fix that?

Comment: Whatever context you are running as does not have permission to execute `/bin/bash`, so anything else it tries after that will fail (no shell available)

Comment: @dcom-launch The user's current context is `sysadm_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t`, it can execute `/bin/bash`. `initrc_t` also could execute `shell_exec_t`. The question why script with type `initrc_exec_t` can't run bash?

Comment: `audit2allow -a -l -M initrc_exec_failure`